# How do you remove a virtual monitor on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I've installed software of Splashtop on my windows 8 laptop to use my tablet as a second monitor. But it didn't work well so I removed the Splashtop software from my laptop. But it seems it doesn't removed the virtual driver or whatever it is called. So now it thinks that my full hd monitor only supports 1024x768 and it thinks that this single monitor is actually 2 screen. Long story short, my whole monitor set-up is ruined and I want to restore it. How to?

Answer (score 1):

Select the "fake" monitor and change the option 'Multiple Displays' to 'remove monitor' then hit APPLY! This will solve the issue